# Saving Edited .xslx Worksheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I've been trying to edit a .xslx worksheet using python and I have been successfully able to alter the cells value but when I use the save command from openpyxl, close the program, and open the excel spreadsheet, no changes have been saved. I have attached the code below and I would appreciate it if you could help me. I have tried reading other stackoverflow posts but when I try what they suggest it still doesn't work so I've turned to creating my first post here.

```
def editStock(choice, edit, stockSymbol):
    sheet = setup()
    stockRow = getStockRow(stockSymbol)
    if choice == 7 or choice == 3 or choice == 2 or choice == 1:
        print("Before")
        print(sheet.cell(row = stockRow, column = choice).value)
        sheet.cell(row = stockRow, column = choice).value = edit
        print("After")
        print(sheet.cell(row = stockRow, column = choice).value)
    else:
        sheet.cell(row = stockRow, column = choice).value = float(edit)

    workbook = getWorkBook()
    workbook.save(filename="Stocks.xlsx")
```

Here's my `setup()`:

```
def setup():
    directory = "C:\\Users\\shrey\\Desktop"
    directory = directory.lower()
    os.chdir(directory)
    spreadname = "Stocks.xlsx"
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(spreadname)
    sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]
    return sheet
```

Here's my `getWorkBook()` for reference:

```
def getWorkBook():
    directory = "C:\\Users\\shrey\\Desktop"
    directory = directory.lower()
    os.chdir(directory)
    spreadname = "Stocks.xlsx"
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(spreadname)
    return workbook
```

Here's my output when I call `editStock()`:

```
Before
None
After
Dec-21-2021
```

And proof that it doesn't work: [date is not altered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQHW.png)

Sorry, the image is not very clear but the Dec-21-2021 should be right after the 'TSLA'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably actually make a separate test script and share the whole thing, because you probably posted the methods that are working exactly correctly, and people typically will ask for that on stack overflow (I couldn't just grab your code and run it; that should usually be the case)

I wrote this little script to see what the matter was, and for me it worked fine.
But I noticed that there were *two* sheets called Sheet1. So make sure you are looking at the different sheets (the tabs). Once I figured that out, the data showed up just fine.

This code works when I run it, (including if the file already exists):

```
import os
import openpyxl

spreadname = "Stocks.xlsx"
sheetname = "THISONE"
if not os.path.exists(spreadname):
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    workbook.create_sheet(title=sheetname)
else:
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(spreadname)
sheet = workbook[sheetname]

c1 = sheet.cell(row=3, column=6)
c1.value = 123.456

c2 = sheet['B9']
c2.value = 456.321

workbook.save(spreadname)
```

Specifically, it creates a sheet called "THISONE" and the data is there.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you probably can't edit a open spreadsheet (make sure to close Excel, then run the script, then open Excel again). Excel keeps a hidden backup file I believe, I wouldn't be surprise if it overwrites changes to the spreadsheet when you close/save in excel.

Comment: Could it be the fact that I'm calling this function from a different script? I have two scripts logic.py the one with this code and gui.py.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just fixed the issue. Since I was calling my setup() function many times, I was creating a sheet which I would not track and therefore not save to my file. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!